# Can't resolve dependency for module function (restangular.IProvider)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript, bower, restangular

I'm trying to setup restangular for a SPA project but I'm unable to resolve it as a dependency with grunt-tsng. I've installed it using bower (and tsd for typescript definitions from definitelyTyped).

#### grunt task configuration

```
tsng: {
        options: {
            extension: ".ng.ts"
        },
        dev: {
            files: [
                // TODO: Automate the generation of this config based on convention
                {
                    src: ["Client/app/**/*.ts", "!**/*.ng.ts"],
                    dest: "Client/app"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

#### Module app.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

module App {

    var dependencies = [
        "ui.router",
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "restangular"
        ...
    ];

    function configuration(
        $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
        RestangularProvider: restangular.IProvider, <-- here it fails
        ...
```

#### ts.d.ts (reference file)

```
/// <reference path="restangular/restangular.d.ts" />
```

#### grunt error

```
Running "tsng:dev" (tsng) task
Warning: Error: Can't resolve dependency for module function App.config with name restangular.IProvider Use --force to continue.
```

Other dependencies, such as *ui-router*, *ui-bootstrap* etc. are working fine. What could be the cause of this? Are there any incompatibilities known with grunt-tsng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

When executing grunt-tsng, it scans all dependencies/modules etc. to automagically hook them into angular so you don't have to do it yourself. Here two simple rules apply: Dependencies to inject that are your own (e.g. where you have typescript inplementation code present, such as classes in your modules) can be defined simply with their name. E.g.:

```
constructor(service: MyModule.IMyService) {}
```

External dependencies, e.g. from angular itself are declared with the '$' notation. grunt-tsng will assume their dependencies itself are resolved at runtime and thus just hooks them up with their name:

```
constructor($routeProvider: ng.IRouteService) {}
```

But now services in restangular aren't named '$restangular', but just 'restangular'. This leads to the following:

- When declaring it as 'restangular', grunt-tsng will look for implementations in your modules, doesn't find any and fails
- When declaring it as '$restangular', angular will look for providers called '$restangular', doesn't find any and fails

**Conclusion:**

This is retarded.

Comment: Your conclusion has earned my +1. Convention over configuration